# Vuejs-Multiselect how to get just the selected option when enabling the multiple option

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new to VueJS, and i am using [Vuejs-Multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org), enabling the multiple option.

I need to pass the selected value to the `toggleSelected` method .

In this pen, there is a simulation : https://codepen.io/amrigo/pen/arvadE

I see the values are concatenated, eg.: when i choose the first value i can see using console.log : [object Object], choosing the second [object Object],[object Object] and so on.

How can i get just the selected value and so the code value from the options array?

In the html i do use :

```
<div id="app">    
          <multiselect 
            v-model="value" 
            :options="options"
            :multiple="true"
            track-by="name"
            :hide-selected="true" 
            :close-on-select="false"
            :custom-label="customLabel"
            :searchable="false" 
            placeholder="" 
            :show-labels="false"
            @input="toggleSelected(value)"
            >           
          </multiselect>      
            <pre>{{ value }}</pre> 
        </div>
```

In the script i do use :

```
new Vue({
            components: {
                Multiselect: VueMultiselect.default
            },
            data: {
                value: [],
                options: [
                        { name: 'Agriculture', code: '1' },
                        { name: 'Police', code: '2' },
                        { name: 'Medical', code: '3' }                  
                ]
            },
          methods: {
            customLabel (option) {
              return `${option.name}`
            },
            toggleSelected(value) {
              alert( `${value.name}` )
              console.log(' >> '+ `${value}` )
            }
          }
        }).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: do not change `value` because it will compare `options`  to determin show / hide options in view. make a computed is more better.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PvPxoQ

Comment: Thank you @王仁宏 your solution  is very clear, did not know i could access the value in this way using the javascript map

Comment: How can i reset the array so i can have just one value at every time i select one option from the select box ?

Comment: if you mean what value changed,  https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-events
 add @select attr and give a function to access `selectedOption`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation,  to get the selected option you use the @select event.
Example:

```
<multiselect 
    // ... all your props*
    @select="optionSelected">           
</multiselect>


// dont put the brackets (),
  //js will automatically pass the values to toggleSelected
//In your method:
optionSelected(option, id) {
console.log(option)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed property for that. Do something like this:

```
  computed: {
    valueIds() {
      return this.value.map(v => v.id);
    }
  }
```

See this working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/ebbishop/7eku4vf0/

Comment: Thank you @ebbishop